# Maintain scroll position on postback in a ListView with asp.net and Master Pages

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

There are a lot of similar posts in maintaining scroll position after a postback in ASP.NET.  I’ve tried several of them with no success, however, a lot of people seem to be having success with the following Javascript.  I've also tried using .scrollLeft vs. .offsetLeft without any luck as well.

```
var xPos, yPos;
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    alert("Begin Request?");
    if ($get('<%=PanelReportInput.ClientID%>') != null) {
        xPos = $get('<%=PanelReportInput.ClientID%>').offsetLeft;
        yPos = $get('<%=PanelReportInput.ClientID%>').scrollTop;
    }
}

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    alert("End Request?");
    if ($get('<%=PanelReportInput.ClientID%>') != null) {
        $get('<%=PanelReportInput.ClientID%>').offsetLeft = xPos;
        $get('<%=PanelReportInput.ClientID%>').scrollTop = yPos;
    }
}
```

I have the above javascript in a file called:  ScrollPosition.js  that is pulled into my Master Page below.  **I get both alerts**, but when I debug this code, both xPos and yPos have a value of 'undefined'.  Below is my .aspx page, but in the above JavaScript code, I've also tried using '<%=UpdatePanelMain.ClientID%>' as well as '<%=DailyStoreListView.ClientID%>' and '<%=DailyStoreListView.ClientID%>'.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DailyOrderSchedule.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Main.Master"
Inherits="OfficeIntranet.Forms.Warehouse.DailyOrdersSchedule" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %> 

<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="DateStoreSelectoruc"    Src="../../Controls/Warehouse/DateStoreSelector.ascx" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <title>Order Schedule</title>
    <link href="../../Styles/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderPageHeading" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderBody"    runat="server">
    <div id="headerE" runat="server" style="text-align: center; width: auto;">
        <asp:Label ID="MainH" CssClass="headerText" runat="server">Order Schedule</asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="headVersion" CssClass="textarea" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelMain" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PanelReportInput" Width="980px" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Inset" BorderWidth="0px" Style="padding: 10px; text-align: center;">
                <asp:ListView ID="DailyStoreListView" runat="server" GroupItemCount="5" GroupPlaceholderID="GPH" style="width:940px"
                    ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder" OnItemDataBound="lv_ItemDataBound" >
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <div runat="server" style="padding: 2px; width: 932px; height:740px; overflow:scroll">
                            <div id="CalendarDays" style="padding: 2px">
                                <div class="SPAWeekFiller5">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="SPAWeekDays" style="margin-right: 2px">Friday</div>
                                <div class="SPAWeekFiller">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="SPAWeekDays">Thursday</div>
                                <div class="SPAWeekFiller">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="SPAWeekDays">Wednesday</div>
                                <div class="SPAWeekFiller">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="SPAWeekDays">Tuesday</div>
                                <div class="SPAWeekFiller">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="SPAWeekDays">Monday</div>
                                <div class="SPAWeekFiller">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div style="clear: both; padding: -1px;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="groupPlaceholder" runat="server"></div>
                        </div>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <GroupTemplate>
                        <div style="padding: 6px 0px 6px 6px; width: 910px;" id="GTdIV">
                            <div id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></div>
                            <div style="clear: both; padding: 4px;"></div>
                        </div>
                    </GroupTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate >
                        <uc:DateStoreSelectoruc ID="DateStoreSelectorControl" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EmptyItemTemplate>
                        <div style="padding: 5px; height: 220px; width: 170px; float: left;">
                        </div>
                    </EmptyItemTemplate>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <div style="padding: 10px; background: #CACACA; width: 930px;">
                        No Records Found.
                        </div>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is the Master Page

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Main.master.cs" Inherits="OfficeIntranet.MasterPages.Main" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>My Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="True" >
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="../Scripts/ScrollPosition.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Panel ID="wrapperP" runat="server">
        <div id="art-page-background-simple-gradient"></div>
        <div id="art-page-background-glare">
            <div id="art-page-background-glare-image"></div>
    ...
```

If anyone has any thoughts on what I’m doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate any help/suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript is in a separate file?

In that case, tags in the form `<%=something%>` in your Javascript are not going to be replaced by the actual values you want.  That only works if your Javascript is inline, part of the page.

This is because the `<% %>` tags are interpreted by the ASP.NET compiler on the web server before it sends the web page to your browser.  The tags are replaced by the actual evaluated values, as you know.  The external Javascript file is never processed by the web server:  it is pulled in by the browser when it interprets the processed page.

Comment: So based on my aspx page above, what tag should I be looking for the actual value from the interpreted HTML?  Would it be the 'PanelReportInput' tag?  I have a master page, so doesn't my JavaScript have to be in a separate file?

Comment: One simple solution would be wrapping your `PanelReportInput` tag in an ordinary HTML `div` tag, inside the `UpdatePanel`'s `ContentTemplate`, and assigning it a unique ID.  You would then use that ID in place of the `PanelReportInput` tag's client ID.

Comment: OK, I've got the same JavaScript as above with this change:  if ($get('<%=divScrollable.ClientID%>') != null) {
                xPos = $get('<%=divScrollable.ClientID%>').offsetLeft;
                yPos = $get('<%=divScrollable.ClientID%>').scrollTop;
            }, only I'm using "divScrollable" instead of 'PanelReportInput', and I've put the JavaScript at the bottom of my aspx page below the ending 'UpdatePanel' line.  And I've put a <div id="divScrollable" runat="server"> above the 'PanelReportInput' panel.  I've got a breakpoint where it assigns xPos, but it never goes there.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear.  Instead of `$get('<%=divScrollable.ClientID%>')`, use `$get('divScrollable')`.  And remove the `runat="server"` attribute from `divScrollable`: you don't need it.

Comment: alert("Begin Request?");
            if ($get('divScrollable') != null) {
                xPos = $get('divScrollable').offsetLeft;
                yPos = $get('divScrollable').scrollTop;
            }
        }

        alert("End Request?");
            if ($get('divScrollable') != null) {
                $get('divScrollable').offsetLeft = xPos;
                $get('divScrollable').scrollTop = yPos;
            }
        }
    </script>        Again, I'm getting the alerts, but it never stops at the assignment to xPos?  Meaning 'divScrollable' is always null?

Comment: I'm wondering whether `divScrollable` is in the wrong place.  Try moving it so that it contains the entire `UpdatePanel`. See if that helps.  I'm thinking that maybe when `BeginRequestHandler` is called, `divScrollable` may not exist yet.

Comment: Darn, that didn't work either.  It talks about moving this to a discussion, is that what I should do?

Comment: @Craig  Sounds like a good idea (moving to chat).  I think we need to look at the generated HTML source from the rendered page. We need to see whether `divScrollable` is rendered, and whether its id value is still "divScrollable" at that point.

Comment: I see the following rendered code:  <div id="ContentPlaceHolderBody_divScrollable" style="overflow: auto">  And right below that is:  <div id="ContentPlaceHolderBody_UpdatePanelMain">  As for entering a chat room, I can see I could enter a Javascript chat room, but do I go there and ask the above question or how would I know when you would be available and in the chat room?

Comment: If I change my $get statements to go after 'ContentPlaceHolderBody_divScrollable', the NULL test doesn't fail, but both xPos and yPos come back as zeroes.

Comment: Supposedly, `offsetLeft` returns offset relative to the offset parent, but what the offset parent can be depends on such things as whether you have `position:relative` set on any of the element's parents.  And, I should have asked earlier: are you scrolling vertically, horizontally, or both, and are you scrolling the whole page or just a block within the page?

Comment: Only scrolling vertically.  I'm pretty sure it would just be a block within the page.

Comment: Any progress?  If you are still where you were on Feb 9, I would look into how `offsetLeft` is calculated, and how it's affected by the CSS `position` property.

Comment: I appreciate all of your ideas.  Yes, I'm still where I left off, but I've had to move on.  The users are just going to have to live with the screen popping back to the top every time.  It's interesting that it seems to work for a lot of people.  They're probably just a whole bunch smarter!